# asp.net mvc4 vs2012 vs vs2010

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

I am planning to start a new project on ASP.Net MVC 4.

The issue at hand is : do all the functionality present in Vs2012 can be used from Vs2010 by using this [vsix](http://www.microsoft.com/web/handlers/webpi.ashx?command=getinstallerredirect&appid=MVC4VS2010_Loc).

I really need to know whether this upgrade will help me with something of value for the money I spend updating the VS version.
Also another question would be if the updates for vs2012 plan to be extended to vs2010 with the update releases like this [one](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2012/12/14/announcing-the-asp-net-and-web-tools-2012-2-release-candidate.aspx).

Please include any links and suggestions for this matter at hand in your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you don't want to use ASP.NET 4.5 features (e.g. access to unvalidated request data), You can go with VS2010 & MVC 4 and your target framework would be 4.0 because MVC 4 is written on top of ASP.NET 4.0

Comment: please provide some documentation/links for this facts.

Comment: you can download MVC 4 RTM source code from http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/ official repository and can open & compile source with VS2010